# Unable to generate tables from entities

Tags: eclipse, jpa, ejb

I'm trying to use JPA Tools in Eclipse in order to *Generate tables from entities*.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700728/unable-to-generate-jpa-entities-from-hsqldb) states that I should perform several action in order to do something similar (creating Entities from Tables). I followed these instruction only to fail again.

I'm using Maven to manage my project and not Eclipse's "Enterprise project creation" as described [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0712_barcia/0712_barcia.html).

Since no message appeared I looked at Eclipse's log, where I saw a *HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Persistence unit not found: 'null'* log. Not sure why I get this log, since Eclipse recognizes my persistence.xml file within the project.

Comment: What part of Entity Generation isn't working for you?  Can you describe the issue in more detail?  The HibernateConsoleRuntimeException may or may not be related.  With some more info I may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: The entity generation form opens up, I mark "Export to Database" option as activated, and Finish. The schema.ddl file and DB tables are not created.

Comment: My guess is that the hibernate runtime is unable to build your persistence unit based on your Maven project structure.  I suggest posting something to the Hibernate Tools forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that Dali has a problem even in Eclipse Juno, As stated [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/138112/435554/#msg_435554), with some rewiring of the source folder and facet it was fixed. Not the best solution though since Dali should recognize Maven's standard directory...

Comment: The Dali tools support the standard Maven configuration in Juno as noted in the following two bugs: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=251323 , https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357810.

Answer (score 0):

I get the error when generating JPA entity using `JPA Tools > Generate Entities From Tables...` i use this instead: `New > Other... > JPA Entities From Tables`